# UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl in tabbed application

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I am trying to use a UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl in a tabbed application.  However I cannot see the 'trigger' ie the page curl as it is hidden behind the tab bar.  Is it possible to use UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl in a tabbed application?

```
    UIViewController *pageCurlViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MapOptionsViewController"];
[pageCurlViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl];
[self presentModalViewController:pageCurlViewController animated:YES];
```

That will programatically trigger the page curl, but when I close it I cannot open it again as the 'curl' is hidden behind the tabs.

This is a tabbed application in Storyboard.  Not sure if that has something to do with it or might be messing it up.  Maybe I need to set this up in the storyboard but I am not entirely sure how.

Comment: Also tried to remove code and setup segue in storyboard that is 'modal' and 'partial curl' but I still see the same behavior.